# Source of icons in adaptive apps search?

Tags: firefox-os

I have [an app](https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/rotogamesq/) in Firefox Marketplace, and for the app I have specified an [Open Web App manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Developing/Manifest) which tells Firefox OS which icon to use on the home screen.

Now, on the left most screen in Firefox OS 1.0.1, then I get to the search screen which integrates [adaptive app search](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-adaptive-search-discover-personalized-apps). Here can I find many mobile web sites, and they all have pretty icons, most of them circular, with the web sites' logos nicely featured. These icons look like tailored for Firefox OS. Nevertheless, for the web sites that I checked I could neither find an Open Web App manifest nor a corresponding favicon or [touch icon](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html).

*Where do the icons on the search screen come from? Did Mozilla possibly create them manually?*

I am asking this as a developer, interested in what ways there are to specify icons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results from the adaptive app search are coming from [everything.me](http://everything.me/). The icons don't seem to be generated directly from the site favicon or touch icons or even icons specified in an openwebapp manifest (most sites from the search results don't even have one). I think they have been created manually or with a smart algorithm choosing the best available option for each site added in everything.me's catalogue. Some icons e.me returns seem to have been generated from other site assets (ex. the logo image) in the site, that is different from what is available as the site (fav/touch)icons.

Comment: That adaptive app search is based on everything.me I was also told in the
Mozilla support forum. everything.me is quite popular on Android as well, with
1,000,000 to 5,000,000 installs according to Google Play. So it's safe to
assume that at least some publishers see benefit in submitting an app to
everything.me, which is possible via the
[SUGGEST MY MOBILE WEB SITE](http://everything.me/publishers/add/) form.
Submitting an app involves uploading an icon according to guidelines, and there
we are: *"All web apps icons on Everything.me appear in a round shape, make sure
[…]"*